# Should i learn hyperledger composer even if its depreciated

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Many courses are teaching composer first
And then fabric that too older versions of it. So should i learn that course ?
Or should i look for something which teaches fabric 2.x and is composer used in industry ?

Comment: Hyperledger Composer is depreciated long back and it's nowhere used. If you are new to HLF then start with the Fabric v2.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend investing any time learning Hyperledger Composer. It is more than deprecated, it is end of life and it would not be sensible to be using it in any sort of production environment now. You should focus your efforts on learning Hyperledger Fabric 2.x